# Preventing Windows from using Alt+Shift key combination to switch locale

Tags: mfc, windows-7, windows-vista, windows-xp

Our program requires the user to hold the Alt+Shift keys together in order to carry out some operations. The problem is that Windows uses this combination to switch locale on some setups. Anyone got any ideas as to how we can "override" this behaviour of Windows whilst our program is running? Can we do some sort of message intervention?

Answer (score 0):

if your Code is in C#/MFC then
use `LowLevelKeyboardProc`
LowLevelKeyboardProc is an application-defined or library-defined callback function used with the SetWindowsHookEx function The system calls this function every time a new keyboard input event is about to be posted into a thread input queue.

[Example](http://tamaspiros.co.uk/2007/12/20/c-disable-ctrl-alt-del-alt-tab-alt-f4-start-menu-and-so-on/)